# Python: Mechanize Failing to Send Cookies to Second URL

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize

I'm having serious issues trying to get Mechanize to preserve the cookies set by the first requested URL for when requesting the second URL. In order to test if anything was being sent, I put the following file on my server (cookies.php):

```
<?php
echo "cookies:::";
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

The following is the python file which means to accomplish my goal. I'd like for the cookies set by the first site, which I output for testing, to be outputted by my PHP file as well (aka to be set before the second request):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, BeautifulStoneSoup
import mechanize

from pprint import *

#

class NullCookieProcessor(mechanize.HTTPCookieProcessor):
    def http_request(self, request): return request
    def http_response(self, request, response): return response

opener = mechanize.build_opener(NullCookieProcessor)

request = mechanize.Request('http://www.google.com')
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
cj = mechanize.CookieJar()
cj.extract_cookies(response, request)

pprint(cj)

request2 = mechanize.Request('http://[domain2].com/cookies.php')
cj.add_cookie_header(request2)
response2 = mechanize.urlopen(request2)

print response2.geturl()
print response2.info()  # headers
print response2.read()  # body (readline and readlines work too)
```

The following is the output:

```
<mechanize._clientcookie.CookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='NID', value='50=rkj1MMbufL7KRMj00TMF4rI4x7VNYgzWk5P97V05gBAMVOrYuSbb6-hpXVC3y_eD999uECgnBn7YqZ-ZGB1kmWhc_wQWV9nKlPER4_3BWEVSGU632vXEhgYROAz3QrP5', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.google.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1331337059, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='PREF', value='ID=20342e7c6a6b8f8b:FF=0:TM=1315525859:LM=1315525859:S=RppxtfAGwVsGkZiJ', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.google.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1378597859, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
http://[MY DOMAIN].com/cookies.php
Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2011 23:51:01 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

cookies:::Array
(
)
```

ANY ideas how to get this to work? It should be noted that the above code is copy+pasted from the docs..., and that I've also tried the other sample code provided by the documentation, which can be found here: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request1` and `request2` are from different domains. It is understandable that cookies from `google.com` are not sent to `'[domain2].com'`.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll give this a shot and get right back.